# L"To fix call CDXUTDialog::Init() first. See comments for details."

Tags: direct3d, dxut

After  calling  callback function DXUTCreateDevice()  error  is being returned  from  DXUTgui.cpp  assert  checking.  Assert  says  first  call  CDXUTDialog::Init()  but  where  should i  put  it in  WinMain() ?   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare your DXUT client code to the content of [EmptyProject](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/master/EmptyProject11/EmptyProject11.cpp) and [SimpleSample](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/master/SimpleSample11/SimpleSample11.cpp)--assuming you are using the DXUT11 from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT).

The typical pattern is to create a global variable for `CDXUTDialogResourceManager`, and then call `CDXUTDialog::Init` from `InitApp` before you get a callback from `DXUTCreateDevice`

```
int WINAPI wWinMain( _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow ) 
{ 
    // Enable run-time memory check for debug builds. 
#ifdef _DEBUG 
    _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF ); 
#endif 


    // DXUT will create and use the best device 
    // that is available on the system depending on which D3D callbacks are set below 


    // Set DXUT callbacks 
    DXUTSetCallbackMsgProc( MsgProc ); 
    DXUTSetCallbackKeyboard( OnKeyboard ); 
    DXUTSetCallbackFrameMove( OnFrameMove ); 
    DXUTSetCallbackDeviceChanging( ModifyDeviceSettings ); 


    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceAcceptable( IsD3D11DeviceAcceptable ); 
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceCreated( OnD3D11CreateDevice ); 
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11SwapChainResized( OnD3D11ResizedSwapChain ); 
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11SwapChainReleasing( OnD3D11ReleasingSwapChain ); 
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11DeviceDestroyed( OnD3D11DestroyDevice ); 
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D11FrameRender( OnD3D11FrameRender ); 

    InitApp();  <-- // THIS IS WHERE DXUT GUI WIDGETS GET INITIALIZED, BEFORE THE WINDOW OR DEVICE IS CREATED
    DXUTInit( true, true, nullptr ); // Parse the command line, show msgboxes on error, no extra command line params 
    DXUTSetCursorSettings( true, true ); 
    DXUTCreateWindow( L"SimpleSample11" ); 


    // Only require 10-level hardware, change to D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 to require 11-class hardware 
    // Switch to D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_x for 10level9 hardware 
    DXUTCreateDevice( D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0, true, 800, 600 ); 


    DXUTMainLoop(); // Enter into the DXUT render loop 


    return DXUTGetExitCode(); 
}
```

> Starting a new project using DXUT is not recommended. It's really intended only for maintaining existing code that has dependencies on DXUT while removing dependencies on D3DX11 and other legacy DirectX SDK content. The vast majority of DXUT's functionality is complete overkill for most applications. It's also buggy and really only intended for samples.

Comment: Yeap right now  i am sure  to not use  empty  one and use  existing  solution  minimum  , because of  solution  configured already  and  what i  have to  do  just implement  a logic  and shaders :).   I know  it is  for just  presentation i  use it  because of  window creation and  all  of the  Win api features  , if i  don't use  it  i have to implement   GUI  features  with myself  and  i  do not want to  waste a  time. But as i  am  going deeper  with Direct3D  i  am realizing   that  soon  or later  i have to implement  my  UI.